# Offline CartPole on infinitely long line?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, research, gym, offline-reinforcement-learning

I am tentatively exploring some RL research that involves doing offline RL on a version of the Gymnasium [CartPole](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/classic_control/cart_pole/) where the cart can move on $\mathbb R$, as opposed to the standard version (see link) where the cart can move on $(-4.8, 4.8) \subseteq \mathbb R$.

I have begun looking at the CartPole code [here](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium/blob/main/gymnasium/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py), but I'm neither an expert programmer nor familiar with the Gymnasium codebase.

**Question:** Does anyone have any advice for modifying the Gymnasium CartPole code to support movement on $\mathbb R$? I am not sure how big of a change this would be.

Because I am interested in doing something related to offline RL, I also need to run the CartPole MDP, given a certain policy, and generate a dataset of tuples $\mathcal D = \{ (\mathbf s_t, \mathbf a_t, \mathbf s_{t + 1}, r_t)\}$, over some trajectory or trajectories.

Comment: The default CartPole allows the cart to travel in $(-4.8, 4.8)$ and terminates the episode if the cart leaves $(-2.4, 2.4)$. One possible solution I will explore is to check whether these are simple parameters in the code. If they are, then maybe I can just adjust them to positive and negative infinity and my problem might be at least partly solved.